# How do I change the master audio volume in my app programatically?

Tags: windows-8, media-player

I would like write an app where I can manipulate the currently playing song (from the Music app for example) such as jumping to the next song in playlist, restarting it or setting the volume up.

I **searched the Windows SDK** and **tried all samples** that seemed relevant to my problem, but I could not find anything that would give me a hint regarding how to do this.

So I would like to ask - How do I mute or change the master volume in my Metro (Windows 8) application?

Comment: You got me here pants down! I will put here my tries to solve this :)

Comment: Searched through all the samples in Windows SDK. Not found anything.

Comment: Well you deserved to get that removed at least :p

Comment: @Keyser My problem is here that the platform is so different that I have no idea where to start. I know my way around Windows 7 and earlier. Thanks for the comment though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metro apps are not allowed to make changes to the system settings. So controlling the Master Volume is not possible from within the metro app. that's y Microsoft provides a settings charm where you can change the volume. the setting's charm is available in right side of your screen.

you can go through this link on MSDN for further clarification

[Controllling master volume from with the App](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sv-SE/winappswithhtml5/thread/b4e34a68-038e-4722-b5d6-ea67d55a5c12)